# How to split the table while BCP out to CSV , I have the RECORD NO as the unique key

Tags: sql, csv, bcp, sap-iq

I am using the below code but this BCP out the whole table. I would like to split the table by record no so that I can deal with high record tables which occupied more space than my PC. Any help appreciated. (I am new to BCP).

*call bcp csldbo.Tablename out %dirname%\tablename_IQ.csv -e %dirname%\tablenameerr.txt -c  -t"##" -U UID -P Password -S servicename -r"\r\n"*

Answer (score 0):

I use -F (First line) and -L( Last line) in the exiting command and It works as per my requirement.

call bcp csldbo.Tablename out %dirname%\tablename_IQ.csv -e %dirname%\tablenameerr.txt -c -F 1 -L 1000000 -t"##" -U UID -P Password -S servicename -r"\r\n"